# Multilevel Java generic inheritance using extends on generic parameters

Tags: java, generics

I have

```
public class First<T> {}

public class Second<T extends SomeConcreteClass> extends First<T> {}

public class Third<T> extends Second<T> {} //Compile-time error
```

I get the compile-time error

```
Type argument T is not with bounds of type-variable T.
```

When I contruct a `Third`, I want to be able to give the generic parameter as `SomeConcreteClass` (or derived class thereof), and for a run-time error to be thrown if I've offered up a type that is not part of `SomeConcreteClass`'s inheritance hierarchy.

I would think that the specification in `Second`'s declaration would simply propagate downward, i.e. it should be implicit in the declaration (and any instantiations) of `Third`.

What's with the error?

Comment: "a run-time error to be thrown if I've offered up a type that is not part". I think you cannot get that. "Offering types" happens only at compile-time (and is then erased). If you disable that (by not "offering" any type), you will probably get ClassCastExceptions at some point, but later, not when the instance of Third is constructed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need is

```
public class Third<T extends SomeConcreteClass> extends Second<T>
```

You just need to respecify the bound.  It doesn't propagate like you think it does.

(I'm not positive of the reason for this, but I have some guesses -- what if it was `Third<T> extends Second<Foo<T>>`?  The appropriate bound on `T` isn't obvious, if there even is one.  So instead, it just doesn't propagate automatically; you have to specify it.)

Comment: Ah, so there is no downward propagation. That is quite unfortunate. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

In our case you can probably replace this:

```
public class Third<T> extends Second<T> {}
```

with this:

```
public class Third extends Second<SomeConcreteClass> {}
```

To use the T within the constructor and otherwise within the code such as a member field of type T, then you can do like this:

```
VB2 extends VB1<Frag2>
...
public VB2(Frag2 frag){...

VB1<T extends Frag1> extends CommonVB<T>
...
public V1(T frag){... /// notice the T

CommonV<T extends CommonFragBase> extends BaseVB<T>
...
public CommonVB(T controller) {...

BaseVB<T extends CommonFragBase>
```

That works. The important thing is the generic on the concrete classes had to specify the actual concrete fragment class in order for the other code in the VB class to access its methods.

Comment: wasted an hour on this

Answer (score 1):

You have a downward propagation of the boundary restriction.

If you'd put your code above in generic terms, you will clearly see the restricted declaration. Also, any further inheritance would also need to preserve or further narrow down that restriction. eg :

```
public class First<T> {}

public class Second<U, T1 extends U> extends First<T1> {}

public class Third<V, T2 extends V> extends Second<V,T2> {}
```

Note that it is now clear that you cannot have

```
public class Third<T> extends Second<T> {}
```

As you are missing the required `T2` type information for `Second<V,T2>`. 
When you use a concrete class, this restriction becomes implicit.

Answer (score 0):

`public class Third<T> extends Second<T> {}`

This is a bound mismatch. You can't extend Second with a generic T when you have just specified that second is of type T than extends SomeConcreteClass. When you extend Second, you need to do so with something that is within the scope of SomeConcreteClass.

`public class Third<T> extends Second<ClassThatExtendsSomeConcreteClass> {}`

or just

`public class Third<T> extends Second<SomeConcreteClass> {}`